# ¿Cómo puedo redimensionar una imagen al guardarla a un tamaño fijo con arreglo de bytes?

Tags: java

Utilizo estos métodos al momento de cargar la imagen:

1. Lo pongo en un Jlabel y también lo cargo como un arreglo de bytes
2. Al momento de guardarlo también lo guardo como arreglo de bytes

Mi problema al abrirlo como arreglo de bytes viene en este código:

```
byte[] bytesImg = new byte[1024*10000];
```

que si no pongo esa cantidad al momento de guardar la imagen me sale incompleta.

Al poner este tamaño se solucionó mi problema pero apareció otro: la imágenes eran muy pesadas (de 10MB c/u), por lo que pensé en redimensionarlas, pero no se me ocurre cómo adaptarlo con mis imágenes como arreglo de bytes.

```
//Metodos en clase areglos
public String guardarImagen(byte[] bytesImg, String ref,Empleado em){
        String respuesta = null;

        try {

            File folder = new File("C:\\Perfiles\\Empleados");

            if(!folder.exists()){

            folder.mkdirs();
            }

            if(ref.equals("new")){


            salida = new FileOutputStream("C:/Perfiles/Empleados/Empleado"+em.getCodigo()+".png");

            salida.write(bytesImg);
            salida.close();}
            else if(ref.equals("modificar")){
                salida = new FileOutputStream("C:/Perfiles/Empleados/Empleado"+em.getCodigo()+".png");

                salida.write(bytesImg);
                salida.close();
            }
            respuesta = "La imagen se guardo";

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        return respuesta;
    }

public byte[] abrirImagen(File archivo){

        byte[] bytesImg = new byte[1024*10000];

        try {
            entrada = new FileInputStream(archivo);



            entrada.read(bytesImg);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        return bytesImg;
    }

//*-----------Imagen de perfil metodo en GUI
protected void do_btnCargarImagen_actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

    FileChooser ventana = new FileChooser();

    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPG Y PNG", "jpg" , "png");

    FileChooser.fileCargar.setFileFilter(filter);

    int resultado=FileChooser.fileCargar.showOpenDialog(null);

    if(JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION == resultado){
        //Le damos la ruta donde esta la imagen
        fichero = FileChooser.fileCargar.getSelectedFile();


        System.out.print(fichero.getName() + "");
        try{

        lblPerfil.setText("");
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(fichero.toString());
        icono = new ImageIcon(icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(lblPerfil.getWidth() , lblPerfil.getHeight() , Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)); //Algoritmo de remuestreo
        lblPerfil.setIcon(icono);

    /***************************************/
        //Redimensionar imagen

        /*OutputStream output = null; 

        BufferedImage src = ImageIO.read(fichero);
        BufferedImage dest = new BufferedImage(215, 287, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g = dest.createGraphics();
        AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(215, 287);
        g.drawRenderedImage(src, at);
        ImageIO.write(dest, "JPG", output);

        output.close();*/

        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error abriendo la imagen " + e);
        }

        }

    ////////ABRIR EN BYTES
                            ////Pasamos la ruta donde esta la imagen
        bytesImg = ae.abrirImagen(fichero);


}
```

Comment: No termino de entender cuál es la pregunta: ¿Cómo redimensionar un arreglo? ¿Cómo escalar una imagen a otro tamaño? ¿Cómo comprimirla? ... Quizás también ayude si intentas explicar el motivo por el cual estás haciendo esto.

Comment: Lo que quiero es redimenzionar la imagen a un tamaño fijo digamos 300 x 500 antes de guardarla en la ruta especificada en mi metodo, pero como mi imagen esta como un arreglo de bytes no se como hacerlo. Lo que estoy haciendo es un formulario, al momento de cargar la i magen con el jfilechooser me lo pone en el jlabelPerfil y al a vez se carga como un arreglo de bytes para que si el usuario pone guardar o modificar la imagen se guarde en una ruta por defecto con el metodo write.

Comment: Pero como puede ver en el metodo abrir la doy el tamaño a mi arreglo de bytes de 100*1024 por lo que mis imagenes pesan 10MB si le doy menos tamaño mis imagenes no se guardan completas(dependiendo de la imagen, si la imagen es de menos calidad si carga completa) por lo que digo nuevamente redimensionar la imagen antes de guardarla pero como mis imagenes como arreglo de byes no se me ocurre como

Answer (score 1):

Para redimensionar una imagen se puede de la siguiente forma:

```
ImageIcon orignal = new ImageIcon([arreglo_en_bytes o ubicacion_archivo]);

// nueva imagen ...
ImageIcon nueva100x100 = new ImageIcon(original.getScaledInstance(100,100,0));
```

Ahora si necesita son los nuevos bytes :

```
BufferedImage bi = (BufferedImagE) nueva100x100.getImage();

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

try{

  ImageIO.write(bi,"png|jpg|etc ..", baos);

  byte[] nuevosBytes = baos.toByteArray();

}catch(IOException e){
 ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo haces al revés. Primero averiguas el tamaño del fichero y luego creas (y dimensionas) el array.

- Si tienes un `File`, puedes usar el método `length()`
- Si acabas de abrir un `FileInputStream`, puedes usar el método `available()`. Cuidado con otros `OutputStream`, porque en ellos `available()` puede no ser el tamaño total del Stream (o incluso ser desconocido).

Si no se puede averiguar el tamaño del fichero (por ejemplo te llega via conexión de red), siempre se puede usar un `ByteArrayOutputStream`; lees la imagen por trozos (por ejemplo, de 4096 bytes) y los vas escribiendo en el `ByteArrayOutputStream`; al finalizar puedes extraer el `byte[]` de ese objeto.

Y, para problemas similares que no tengan estas soluciones, siempre está la solución "a lo bruto". Pruebas con un tamaño de 1.000, si no funciona pruebas con 10.000, si no funciona pruebas con 100.000, etc. Naturalmente, mejor usar esta técnica como de ultimísimo recurso.